# Analytics Tag Manager - Set transaction date

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know if there is a way to post to analytics on a specific date instead of the date the transaction was sent to analytics.

e.g. I have an order that starts on the 12th but the conversion page doesn't process until the 19th but I want the transaction to appear on analytics as happening on the 12th.

I'm using tag manager and have setup a data layer like bellow.

Even if there is a way to tweak Gaq push to send data on a different date that would work

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
    'brands'              : <?php echo "'" . $brandnames . "'" ?>,
    'transactionId'       : <?php echo "'" . $orderId . "'" ?>,
    'transactionTotal'    : <?php echo "'" . array_sum($branditems) . "'" ?>,
    'transactionProducts' : [
    <?php foreach ($orderedItems as $item) :  
           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
           $branding = $product->getManufacturer();
            $procat = 'empty';
            $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
                   foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
                    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
                     $procat = $cat->getName();
                     }  ?>            
    <?php if ( $branding == '168') { ?>
        {   
            'brand'    : <?php echo "'" . $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') . "'" ?>,
            'category' : <?php echo "'" . $procat . "'" ?>,
            'name'     : <?php echo "'" . $item->getName() . "'" ?>,
            'sku'      : <?php echo "'" . $item->getSku() . "'" ?>,
            'price'    : <?php echo "'" . $item->getPrice() . "'" ?>,
            'quantity' : <?php echo "'" . $item->getQtyOrdered() ."'" ?>
        },
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    ]
}];
```